# Who is responsible for object conversion?

Tags: java, theory

Let's say I have ClassA and ClassB. ClassA is a controller, and ClassB is a DAO. ClassA, by some trivial means, generates a String. It then needs to store this String in the database, so it calls `someMethod` in ClassB. However, the database needs the value to be a Long before it's stored. In this situation, who is responsible for converting the String to a Long?

**Option A**: ClassA is responsible, and has logic to convert the String into a Long before calling `ClassB#someMethod(Long theLong)`.

**Option B**: ClassB is responsible, and *it* has the logic to convert the String into a Long. ClassA will be calling `ClassB#someMethod(String theString)`.

In a world of best practices, which is correct?

Comment: It depends on who has the canonical representation, whatever that is in your data model.  It's really not possible to give a rule that applies in all contexts.

Comment: Well.. Although I agree with @JimGarrison, I would like to say that, generally, a `DAO` should be responsible only for storing in the DB. You could have a helper method/class which is called from classA to convert string to long and ClassA should pass a long to the DAO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it can be useful to have overloaded methods that take both types of arguments.

For example, in some of my classes, in particular in setter methods, I have methods that take both String and int/long. The reason is that I have a mechanism to serialize an instance to XML, and when I de-serialize it, I use the setField(String) method, which converts the field to its integer/long type, so the class itself used the `setField(String)` variant. When the class is constructed from scratch, I would usually use the `setField(int)` directly.

```
public void setField (String val)
{
    try {
        int v = Integer.parseInt(val);
        setField (v);
    }
    catch (..) {
        ...
    }
}

public void setField (int val)
{
    // can add some range checks here
    this.val = val;
}
```